# Angry IP scanner; where does it store the "comments" file?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, directory, ip

I used "Angry IP Scanner" to find all the devices on my network. (large family with multiple devices each). It has a cool feature where you can add comments for each device. This is great for inventorying all my devices. Now I just need to find the file that those comments (and IPs etc) are stored in, so that I can have a full list, even when some of the devices are offline.

Anybody know where this file would be located (on Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It is in /home//.java/.userPrefs/ipscan/comments/prefs.xml

it maps the comments back to the MAC address